# "flutter on the web" Only the image is displayed in the title of the appbar, but the browser tab is annoying

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

## Want

I want to display only the image in the title of the appbar.

## Code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Container(
          height: 30,
          width: 100,
          child: SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/svg/Logo.svg',
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
            semanticsLabel: 'gflogo',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
      ),
    );
  }
```

## Question

After setting the title of the appbar to something like an image, the browser tab displayed the URL instead of the title.

Can you come up with a way to display the title in the browser tab with the image etc. set in the title of the appbar?

Or is there another better way?

Comment: ```flutter_svg 0.19.3 ``` package does still not support svg file on web

Comment: I know flutter_svg 0.19.3 does still not support on the web. but , i think this problem is same as png, don't you?

Comment: Not suitable for commercial use, but it works.`flutter channnel beta` `flutter upgrade`
 `flutter pub upgrade --null-safety`

Answer (score 1):

Change  tag in index.html in /web folder(not /lib/web)

Answer (score 0):

The package `flutter_svg` that you are using for `SvgPicture.asset` does not support web you will need either to convert your SVG to a custom flutter shape using tools such as [Flutter Shape Maker](https://fluttershapemaker.com/) but it doesn't work well with all SVG, you can also convert your [SVG to PNG](https://svgtopng.com/) and use `Image.asset` instead.